# Scanner doesn't see file Java

Tags: java

I don't really understand whats the problem but my scanner just can't see the file I'm passing. I tried moving file to src, still doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 File file = new File("src/1.txt");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
 int n = sc.nextInt();
 int [][] graph = new int [n][n];
 for (int x =0; x<n; x++)
     for (int y=0; y<n;y++)
         graph[x][y] = sc.nextInt();

}
```

File is stored at C:\Users\evluc\IdeaProjects\ka1\src\com\company

Comment: What is error/problem you are facing while running this

Comment: you are stating that the file is stored at src\com\company. 
So try \src\com\company\1.txt

Comment: what is the directory oh the class you are in?

Comment: I assume it is a path problem and the file is not in the correct folder. Try using absolute path and then narrow down the issue with relative paths.

Comment: You should try `"Users/evluc/IdeaProjects/ka1/src/com/company/1.txt"`

Comment: move your file from this location C:\Users\evluc\IdeaProjects\ka1\src\com\company  to C:\Users\evluc\IdeaProjects\ka1\src or change this line in code File file = new File("src/1.txt"); as File file = new File("src/com/company1.txt");

Answer (score 0):

You can try `file.getCanonicalPath()` or `file.getAbsolutePath()` to determine what the path of the file is you're trying to read and can therefore find out what's wrong with your relative path. I assume this is just a relative path issue and has nothing to do with the actual routine you're trying to access the file. If you know were you are pointing with the `File` object you will also know how you have to change your relative path. That is always the first thing to check when working with relative paths.

Comment: yeah. if that program is present in same directory. it's fine to use only name here

Comment: i used getAbsolutePath() and it showed the exact path I'm passing into File file = new File("src/1.txt");  Yet scanner says: unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: @mak I don't have the time to verify it myself with code but taking this https://www.journaldev.com/848/java-file-path-absolute-canonical as an example I doubt that you don't get the absolute path out with both outlined methods I described above. As you can see a relative path is resolved to an absolute path. Maybe I'm missing something but IDK what this should be ;)

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
 File file = new File("C:\Users\evluc\IdeaProjects\ka1\src\com\company\src\1.txt");

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int [][] graph = new int [n][n];
            for (int x =0; x<n; x++)
              for (int y=0; y<n;y++)
                graph[x][y] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: mixing back and front slash isn't recommended and in this case probably won't even work

Answer (score 0):

The input what have you provided `src/1.txt` it is trying to look file at the location : `C:\Users\evluc\IdeaProjects\src\1.txt`.

Either give absolute path for the file or correct your path.